# Get-CimInstance repeats output multiple times

Tags: powershell, cim

I'm trying to get a last boot time report and my script keeps out repeating the same output 8 times, I'm sure its a syntax error. Here is what I have:

```
$ServerName = (Get-Content -Path 
D:\Users\Admin.sa\Desktop\Computerlist.txt)

##### Script Starts Here ######  

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {Get-CimInstance -Cn $Servername -ClassName 
win32_operatingsystem | select csname,lastbootuptime}

Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe the issue is inside your `for` loop. Try:

```
$ServerName = (Get-Content -Path "D:\Users\Admin.sa\Desktop\Computerlist.txt")

##### Script Starts Here ######  

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {Get-CimInstance -Cn $Server -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname,lastbootuptime}

Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

So your issue is that when you do the for loop, you are using the wrong variable. Remember when you use the for-loop, you must use the `$Server` NOT the `$ServerName`

so:

```
$ServerName = (Get-Content -Path 
D:\Users\Admin.sa\Desktop\Computerlist.txt)

##### Script Starts Here ######  

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {Get-CimInstance -Cn $Server -ClassName 
win32_operatingsystem | select csname,lastbootuptime}

Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: this is the exact answer i wrote above an hour ago.

Comment: lol, we probably wrote it at the same time, but don't worry, I up-voted yours, once i saw it.